# Identifying unhandled interrupt

Tags: interrupts, stm32f3, eclipse

I stopped in the middle of debugging a very simple project where I send "hello world\r\n" every couple seconds out of USART2.  The first print hits the console and then I hang in an infinite loop after in `startup_stm32.s`:

```
/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an
 *         unexpected interrupt.  This simply enters an infinite loop, preserving
 *         the system state for examination by a debugger.
 *
 * @param  None
 * @retval : None
*/
    .section .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
Default_Handler:
Infinite_Loop:
  b Infinite_Loop
```

I appear to not be handling an interrupt, but I myself actually have not enabled any interrupts.  I am only using the `HAL_UART_*` API (`HAL_UART_Init`, `HAL_UART_Transmit`, and implemented the `HAL_UART_ErrorCallback`).

#### How can I learn more about what interrupt isn't being handled?

Comment: Presumably by examining the state of the system with a debugger

Comment: Do you have a debugger connected? Check the NVIC registers (ISERx, ISPRx) to see which interrupts are enabled & pending.

Comment: Assuming hardfault has a different handler, what interrupts have you enabled?

Comment: You may be experiencing a hard fault and not even know it. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/432309/81178

Comment: Updated with more info.  I have not enabled any interrupts myself.  I am just using the HAL_UART API in a way that worked on a Nucleo board but not a custom board.  The working code has not changed.  There's seems to be something different between the Nucleo board and mine (STM32F302R8 vs STM32F302C8YX).  My goal is to generally understand what registers/etc to consider in general, to help others who hit that infinite loop.

Comment: @filo you hit the nail on the head.  In this new, simple project, none of the stm32f3xx_it.c was built out.  I'm hitting `HardFault_Handler`, but not able to use this function to gather any more info about where I crashed: https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html,

Comment: Why are you not able to see the program counter (PC) in the hard fault handler?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wrong stack exchange site

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new handler with an infinite loop one at a time until the missing IRQ handler is detected.  It's a slow, but reliable method.  You can find the full list of weak IRQ definitions in the `startup_stm32.s` file.

Example incremental IRQ handler addition to `stm32f3xx_it.c`:

```
void DMA1_CH1_IRQHandler(void) {
  while (1);
}
```

In general, this seems to be an issue of unknown defaults.  Starting a project with all the IRQ handlers implemented is one way to make sure you're not bitten.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I copy pasted the below part of stm32l4xx_it.c file of my UART example source project in STM32cubemx IDE

/**

- @brief This function handles USART1 global interrupt.
  */

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{

HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);

}